# How can I use Powershell to move a list from a development to a production Sharepoint 2010 box?

Tags: list, deployment, powershell, export, production

I'd like to copy a list (and its contents) onto our production server. I've been trying to use the `Export-SPWeb` cmdlet, using [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jorman/copying-lists-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010) as a reference, but I can't seem to get it to cooperate. I've successfully exported the whole web, but not individual lists, which is what I would prefer to do.

This is what I've tried:

```
PS J:\> export-spweb http://mysite -itemurl "lists/mylist" -path "c:\temp\mylist.cmp"
```

This is the (quite unhelpful) error message I get:

```
Export-SPWeb : <nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:13
+ export-spweb <<<<  $web -itemurl "lists/mylist" -path "c:\temp\mylist.cmp"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb:
   SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWe
   b
```

I believe it has to do with the `-itemurl` switch, because, when I take it out, powershell successfully exports the whole web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a slash at the start of the `ItemUrl` parameter.  Your command should look like:

`export-spweb http://mysite -itemurl "/lists/mylist" -path "c:\temp\mylist.cmp"`

[Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/a1f48e70-9360-440f-b160-525fbf2b8412/#ce1daa0a-9e10-46ee-bfd0-4d30fcf69032)

Answer (score 1):

```
export-spweb http://servername/sites/PonniTest/ -itemurl "Lists/Try" -Path C:\raks.cmp
```

Note: Your Url should be terminated with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
Export-SPweb -Identity http://site/sub1/sub2 -Path "c:\lstExport\lstName.cmp" -ItemUrl "/sub1/sub2/lstName" -IncludeUserSecurity -Force -IncludeVersions All
```

Add slash("/") at the start of the ItemUrl parameter.